# When did Macaulay rings become Cohen-Macaulay rings?

Tags: terminology, abstract-algebra

In his book on commutative rings (published 1970), Kaplansky talks about Macaulay rings. In the mid 1970's, I learned some commutative algebra from a student of his, who referred to these rings as Macaulay rings. When I returned to commutative algebra about twenty years later, these rings were now Cohen-Macaulay. When did the change occur?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the name Cohen-Macaulay rings and Macaulay rings areboth due to Zariski and Samuel (*Commutative Algebra*, Volume 2, App. 6, p. 396, 1958):

> Definition 1. Let $A$ be a local ring. The common number of elements of the maximal prime sequence in $A$ is called the hological dimension (or the grade) of $A$, and is denoted by $codh(A)$. If $codh(A)=dim(A)$, we say that $A$ is a **Macaulay ring (or a Cohen-Macaulay ring)**. [emphasis mine]

So, it was Kaplansky's decision to call them just Macaulay ring (see, e.g., Irving Kaplansky, *Commutative Rings*, Chapter 3, p. 84, 1974), but at the same time other authors used the name Cohen-Macaulay ring, e.g., Mario Fiorentini, *[Esempi di anelli di Cohen-Macaulay che non sono di
Gorenstein](http://www.bdim.eu/item?id=RLINA_1971_8_50_2_94_0&fmt=pdf)* (Examples of Cohen-Macaulay rings that are not Gorenstein rings), *Atti della Accademia Nazionale dei Lincei*, Serie 8, Vol. 50, n.2, p. 94–99, 1971. (in italian)